# Colossians 1:16 ASV could we translate "dominions" as "Lordships"?

Tags: colossians

Colossians 1:16 GNT;

> 16. ὅτι ἐν αὐτῷ ἐκτίσθη τὰ πάντα, τὰ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς καὶ τὰ ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς, τὰ ὁρατὰ καὶ τὰ ἀόρατα, εἴτε θρόνοι, εἴτε **κυριότητες** εἴτε ἀρχαὶ εἴτε ἐξουσίαι· τὰ πάντα δι᾿ αὐτοῦ καὶ εἰς αὐτὸν ἔκτισται·

Colossians 1:16 Vulgate;

> 16. quia in ipso condita sunt universa in caelis et in terra visibilia et invisibilia sive throni sive **dominationes** sive principatus sive potestates omnia per ipsum et in ipso creata sunt.

Colossians 1:16 ASV;

> 16. for in him were all things created, in the heavens and upon the earth, things visible and things invisible, whether thrones or **dominions** or principalities or powers; all things have been created through him, and unto him;

Could we translate **κυριότητες** as Lordships rather than dominions which come from the Latin Vulgate **dominationes**, while κυριότητες has a relationship to Kairius κυριός which means Lord, and has a relation to the LORD?

N.B, the LORD is Dominus in Latin Vulgate. Also, DRB translates Dominus as Lord.

DRB translation of Colossians 1:16, dominationes is translated as dominations rather than Lordships.

I hope you get what I am saying.

Comment: Up-voted +1 and **thank you** for pointing this out. _Kurieuo_ is found seven times (a significant number, relating to perfection) referring to the 'exercising of lordship'. _Kuriotes_ is found four times (a significant number relating to the earth; north, south ,east and west) referring to the domain over which lordship is exercised. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the answer is "yes".  However, in English idiom, "Lordship" usually refers to the person and not the estate over which the Lord rules.  [Despite this, Thayer lists "lordship" as a possible translation.]  This is the reason that the Latin form "dominion" is preferred because it is less ambiguous.

More specifically, BDAG lists the following meaning for κυριότης -

(2) **the majestic power that the κυριός wields, *ruling power, lordship, dominion***, eg, Dude 8, 2 Peter 2:10

(3) **a special class of angelic powers, *bearers of the ruling power, dominions***, eg, Col 1:16, Eph 1:21.